# Amazon's Product Advertising API is returning wrong pagination/results values

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-product-api

I'm working on an app which returns products from Amazon:

```
client.itemSearch({ 
      condition: 'New',
      keywords: decodeURI(req.query.q),
      merchantId: 'Amazon',
      itemPage: page,
      responseGroup: 'ItemAttributes,Offers,Images' + ',ShippingCharges'
    }, (err, results, response) => {
       // work on results / response
    })
```

... returns responses like this:

[image]

Problem is that the API is straight up lying when the page is set to 2, 3 etc. The values are as follows:

- On page 1: 65 total, 7 pages
- On page 2: 56 total, 6 pages
- On page 3: 45 total, 5 pages
- On page 4: 38 total, 4 pages
- On page 5: **ERROR** (the whole response is undefined)

It really looks like this API is simply broken.

I need to know how many pages there are to display pagination on the frontend. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: **Ref `page` value** - Please clarify what the exact object `property:value` combinations your summary (_on page 1: 65 total, 7 Pages_) is derived from. I do see the object above, but that object doesn't show the same number in your summary - or their origins.

Comment: @RandyCasburn The screenshot in question was using `Braun Razor` as the input. Please let me know if you can't reproduce this error

Comment: That doesn't address my question. There is a disparity between the result object shown above and the _straight up lying_ assertion. The **ERROR** shown for page 5 makes sense looking at the result object - it says there are `TotalPages: [ '4']` - of course page 5 will **ERROR**.  So I'm attempting to understand that disparity. Showing congruency between your data points would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the Amazon API I can see:

`TotalPages  Total number of pages in the response. Each page can return up to ten items.`

So I think that you can know the total number of pages doing

`const pages = Math.ceil(1.4)(TotalResults/10)`

Also, I see that you have the "New" flag. You are filtering responses so maybe items are being filtered but the number of pages not.